# Can't get unicode symbols in math mode

Tags: unicode-math, cyrillic

I am trying for about a week to launch `unicode-math` package with XeLaTeX and got nothing. PDF is created well but all Cyrillic symbols in math mode are skipped. I tried using different math fonts - no progress at all. In log file, I found low-level error:

```
Missing character: There is no [cyrillic letter from input] in font cmmi12!
```

But all fonts used in document are Unicode ones.

Here is a file I want to be processed well (of course it is UTF-8).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}  

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[russian]{hyperref}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
Просто буквы % Plain letters
$$Память: M_{доп}(n) = \Theta(N)$$ % Memory: M_add(n) = \Theta(n)
\end{document}
```

Looking for your help.

Comment: What makes you think there are glyphs in Latin Modern Math for Cyrillic chars?

Comment: @JosephWright Actually i am trying fonts that are mentioned in `unicode-math` doc as Unicode-compatible ones. I also tried xits-math and don't succeed as well.

Comment: I think you slightly miss my point. Unicode fonts don't have _every_ Unicode glyph in them, they have a subset but in predictable slots. In the case of a math mode font, this means defined 'mathematical meaning' glyphs. That I know of there are not such math mode slots for Cyrillic letters: one is expected to use Roman chars for maths. As such, it's entirely unsurprising that you don't get all of the text appearing in your output.

Comment: The following is quoted from *The Comprehensive LᴬTᴇX Symbol List*:
For example, the symbol for an impulse train or Tate-Shafarevich group (“Ш”) is actually an uppercase sha in the Cyrillic alphabet. (Cyrillic is supported by the OT2 font encoding, for instance). While a sha can be defined numerically as “`{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont\char88}`” it may be more intuitive to use the OT2 font encoding’s “`SH`” ligature: “`{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont SH}`”.

Comment: @JosephWright Oh, now i see now. So, as I understood, these math-fonts are Unicode-based fonts without most of Unicode symbols, including cyrillic letters; so I do agree that they shouldn't be output in sample above. But if i want cyrillic and other letters in mathmode, could you help?

Comment: @Symbol1 This may work, but that's too bad. `\text` is shorter and easier to use. I want just to place cyrillic (and others) symbols and I want them to be typeset properly.

Comment: The English equivalent would be `\[\text{Memory: }M_{\textup{Dol}}(n)=\Theta(N)\]` Without `\text` the typesetting would be wrong. Your `Память` is not math too.

Comment: @Symbol1 Ow. As I see, this is actuall thing I need to do.

Comment: @egreg Yes, i know. That is just an example. Actually, I am interested in cyrillic letters for indexes and etalons in physics (meters, Tesla and others).

Comment: @LapshinDmitry Textual subscripts should be in `\textup` anyway.

Comment: Now that this question is resolved, could you adjust the title of this question to be more specific please? It won't archive well in its current form.

Comment: @WillRobertson changed. Actually, now I took in the problem and understand, why it should be called like this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a problem of cyrillic math characters; if the text were English, the correct input would be

```
Letters only
\[
\text{Memory: } M_{\textup{add}}(n) = \Theta(N)
\]
```

because Память and доп are not math. The difference becomes clear when comparing this with the output of

```
\[
Memory: M_{add}(n) = \Theta(N)
\]
```

[image]

The bottom formula is clearly wrong. Textual subscripts are not math variables, so they should be typeset in the normal text font (upright), thus either `\textnormal` or `\textup` (the latter is shorter). Of course, you can define your own command for them.

Here's the complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}  

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[russian]{hyperref}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

Просто буквы % Plain letters
\[
\text{Память: } M_{\textnormal{доп}}(n) = \Theta(N)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

It would be a different problem if you wanted to use a cyrillic letter as a math variable, but your case is not this one.

If you need cyrillic letters as math variables, here's a way to set them up:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=modern]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}  

\usepackage[russian]{hyperref}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\newcommand{\makecyrmathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symcyrletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="409
\loop\ifnum\count255<"44F
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makecyrmathletter{\count255}
\repeat

\begin{document}
\[
(д+ф)^{2}=д^{2}+2дф+ф^{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

What does `\makecyrmathletter` do? Let's review it. The idea is that it takes as argument an integer and performs some magic. We use it in the following loop where the first cycle is

```
\makecyrmathletter{\count255}
```

with `\count255` having the value `"410` (hexadecimal), which corresponds to А U+0410 CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A.

In order to understand the code, I'll assume the explicit value is passed. The first level expansion is then

```
\begingroup\lccode`a="410\lowercase{\endgroup
\Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symcyrletters\endcsname\space "410
```

The strange `\begingroup` construction is used to obtain the letter from the number: we can loop through numbers, not letters. So inside the group, the `\lccode` of the letter `a` (the backtick notation is called “alphabetic constant”) to `"410`. With this setting, `\lowercase` will scan through its argument, changing every character token into its “lowercase” counterpart, but it actually uses the `\lccode` table. Then the result will be delivered to be scanned again. Hence we obtain

```
\endgroup\Umathcode`А="0 \csname symcyrletters\endcsname\space "410
```

(only the `a` is changed, control sequences pass through `\lowercase` with no change). The `\endgroup` does its job, namely to revert the change of `` \lccode`a `` to what it was before, and vanishes.

Then the `\Umathcode` assignment is performed. It assigns `А` a math code, that is a new interpretation when found in math mode. The `=` should be followed by three numbers. The first one states the type of the object; 0 means an ordinary symbol; the second one tells XeTeX from what font family to take it. `\csname symcyrletters\endcsname` produces the number that has been assigned with the previous `\DeclareSymbolFont` declaration. Using a symbolic name we don't need to know what number is actually assigned. The third number tells XeTeX what slot the character should be taken from and we obviously choose `"410`, so a Cyrillic `А`. The three numbers should be separated by a space, which is explicit in the first case; we need `\space` in the second case, because leaving a blank space would not work. Since expansion is performed when looking for numbers, this `\space` is transformed in an actual space token.

A simpler loop can be used with `expl3`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_step_inline:nnn { "410 } { "44F }
 {
  \Umathcode #1 = "0 ~ \use:c{ symcyrletters } ~ #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: I would use `M_{\mathrm{add}}(n)` instead of `\textup` to avoid that the index can change along with the surrounding textfont (e.g. if this is in bold). For the "Memory:" it depends on the meaning.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The choice between `\mathrm` and `\textup` is subjective; the safest is, in my opinion, `\textnormal`, but having a formula in a boldface context should be quite rare (that is, never). Using a personal command reliefs from the burden. The word “Memory” instead should inherit the font from the context.

Comment: Good solution, but not for my problem --- i really need cyrillic as part of math. Still, great thanks!

Comment: @LapshinDmitry I've added the method for defining the letters as math (italic) variables. If you don't want italics, change the `{it}` into `{n}`.

Comment: @egreg Oh, that's nice to have too! That is even a little bit closer to my needs.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry If you don't say what are your needs, it's just guessing.

Comment: The code is not readable. I don't understand it, so I can't use it.

Comment: @facetus What's the unreadable part? The idea in the last code is to loop over the Cyrillic block and assign a suitable math code to each letter.

Comment: The last piece of the code (the loop) is actually quite transparent. The first part I cannot comprehend even after thorough search of various documentation. What a backtick is doing? What is lccode and why it is needed? How is that an open curly brace is between `begingroup` and `endgroup`? Why you are lower casing `\Umathcode`? I don't understand what this code is doing and how. I am a professional SW engineer with 30 years of experience and I couldn't decipher it.

Comment: @facetus I added the explanation. Feel free to ask again if something is not clear. TeX is quite arcane in some of its parts.

Comment: Thank you for an explanation! So `a` is used as just a placeholder to convert it to `#1`? Why just `\Umathcode #1 =` won't work?

Comment: @facetus Good question! Actually it would, but probably I first wrote different code that required the letter and simply changed a part.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

There has been some discussion about Cyrillic in math but the issue is still open: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/29

As [Joseph mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/unicode-math-doesnt-work-at-all#comment468533_201239) you need fonts with the glyph. In case of math (if you don't switch to a text font with `\text{..}`) you also need to set mathcodes. E.g.;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS} %for text
\setmathfont[]{xits-math.otf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\newcommand\addmathletter[1]{%
  \Umathcode  #1="\mathchar@type\mathalpha \csname sym\um_symfont_tl\endcsname #1\relax
}
\int_step_inline:nnnn {1024}{1}{1154}{
  \addmathletter{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Просто буквы % Plain letters
$$Память: M_{доп}(n) = \Theta(N)$$ % Memory: M_add(n) = \Theta(n)
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The `\Umathcode` line is copied and adapted from an old message in the xetex list and I don't what the quoting sign at the begin is doing there ...)

Comment: The `"` is the hexadecimal prefix, as usual.

Comment: @egreg: Yes I suspected this. But is seems not to make a difference if it is there or not. OK. Looking at it `\mathchar@type\mathalpha` is 7 and so "7=7.

Comment: Since math types are from 0 to 7 it really doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Exactly the result I wanted. Thanks a lot. I know that non-math text shouldn't be at math-mode, but I need cyrillic, and I got it.

Comment: Hmm, a bit late to this answer but I ran into needing this today as well, and the above code with xelatex 0.999992 throws an error on the `}` after `\relax` with the log file saying "End of file on the terminal!". Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun - in the general case:

[image: general algebra]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}



%See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/cant-get-unicode-symbols-in-math-mode

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\newcommand{\makecyrmathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symcyrletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="409
\loop\ifnum\count255<"44F
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makecyrmathletter{\count255}
\repeat

%-----------
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Armenian}
%\familydefault = \rmdefault
\DeclareSymbolFont{armletters}{\encodingdefault}{NotoSerifArmenian(0)}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makearmmathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symarmletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="530
\loop\ifnum\count255<"587
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makearmmathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Georgian}
\DeclareSymbolFont{geoletters}{\encodingdefault}{NotoSerifGeorgian(0)}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makegeomathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symgeoletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="109F
\loop\ifnum\count255<"10FA
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makegeomathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\setmainfont{Noto Serif Lao}
\DeclareSymbolFont{laoletters}{\encodingdefault}{NotoSerifLao(0)}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makelaomathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symlaoletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="0E80
\loop\ifnum\count255<"0EDF
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makelaomathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
\DeclareSymbolFont{egyletters}{\encodingdefault}{NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs(0)}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makeegymathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symegyletters\endcsname\space #1
}
%\count255="13000
%\loop\ifnum\count255<"1342E %too many?
%  \advance\count255 by 1
%  \makeegymathletter{\count255}
%\repeat
% has 1000 glyphs
\makeegymathletter{"13000}
\makeegymathletter{"13068}
\makeegymathletter{"1307B}
\makeegymathletter{"130D8}
\makeegymathletter{"131C1}



%-----------
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}


\begin{document}

Cyrillic:

\[
(д+ф)^{2}=д^{2}+2дф+ф^{2}м
\]

Armenian:

\[
(է+թ)^{2}=գ^{2}+2ե+ճդ^2-ա
\]

Georgian:

\[
(დ+ლ)^{2}=შ^{2}+2ლ+დშ^2-ა
\]

Lao:

\[
(ມ+ວ)^{2}=ມ^{2}+2ນ+ສວ^2-ກ
\]

Egyptian Hieroglyphs:

\[
(+)^{2}=^{2}+2+^2-
\]

\end{document}
```

And, of course, symbols can be combined:

[image: for fun two]

Here is a way using `fontspec` package's `NFSSFamily=` font option to refer to the font families, rather than relying on the internal auto-generated name. And the other font options, such as colour and scale, are also available.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\newfontfamily\fcyr{Noto Serif}[Colour=blue,NFSSFamily=mycyr]
\newfontfamily\farm{Noto Serif Armenian}[Colour=red,NFSSFamily=myarm]
\newfontfamily\fgeo{Noto Serif Georgian ExtraBold}[Colour=brown,NFSSFamily=mygeo]
\newfontfamily\flao{Noto Serif Lao}[Scale=1.2,NFSSFamily=mylao]
\newfontfamily\fegy{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}[Colour=blue,Scale=1.1,NFSSFamily=myegy]

%See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/cant-get-unicode-symbols-in-math-mode

\DeclareSymbolFont{cyrletters}{\encodingdefault}{mycyr}{m}{it}
\newcommand{\makecyrmathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symcyrletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="409
\loop\ifnum\count255<"44F
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makecyrmathletter{\count255}
\repeat

%-----------
\DeclareSymbolFont{armletters}{\encodingdefault}{myarm}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makearmmathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symarmletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="530
\loop\ifnum\count255<"587
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makearmmathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\DeclareSymbolFont{geoletters}{\encodingdefault}{mygeo}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makegeomathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symgeoletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="109F
\loop\ifnum\count255<"10FA
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makegeomathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\DeclareSymbolFont{laoletters}{\encodingdefault}{mylao}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makelaomathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symlaoletters\endcsname\space #1
}
\count255="0E80
\loop\ifnum\count255<"0EDF
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \makelaomathletter{\count255}
\repeat



%-----------
\DeclareSymbolFont{egyletters}{\encodingdefault}{myegy}{m}{n}
\newcommand{\makeegymathletter}[1]{%
  \begingroup\lccode`a=#1\lowercase{\endgroup
  \Umathcode`a}="0 \csname symegyletters\endcsname\space #1
}
%\count255="13000
%\loop\ifnum\count255<"1342E %too many?
%  \advance\count255 by 1
%  \makeegymathletter{\count255}
%\repeat
% has 1000 glyphs
\makeegymathletter{"13000}
\makeegymathletter{"13068}
\makeegymathletter{"1307B}
\makeegymathletter{"130D8}
\makeegymathletter{"131C1}



%-----------


\begin{document}

Cyrillic:

\[
(д+ф)^{2}=д^{2}+2дф+ф^{2}м
\]

Armenian:

\[
(է+թ)^{2}=գ^{2}+2ե+ճդ^2-ա
\]

Georgian:

\[
(დ+ლ)^{2}=შ^{2}+2ლ+დშ^2-ა
\]

Lao:

\[
(ມ+ວ)^{2}=ມ^{2}+2ນ+ສວ^2-ກ
\]

Egyptian Hieroglyphs:

\[
(+)^{2}=^{2}+2+^2-
\]

Combined:

\[
(_{ມ^უ}+)^{2}=^{2}+\frac{2}{է}+ф(Զ^2)-Ⴔ
\]

\end{document}
```