# How to get around ! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared if using XeTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, math-fonts, opentype, mathtime

This is a follow-up question to [Using ANY Stix Two Math OTF character in text and math modes without loading it as math font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690061/using-any-stix-two-math-otf-character-in-text-and-math-modes-without-loading-it/690087?noredirect=1#comment1712378_690087).

Using David Carlisle's method, I made the following package file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{Stix2OTFCalligraphic}[07/01/2023]

\newfontface\StixTwoMathZero{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixtwocal,Script=Math]
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwocal}{TU}{stixtwocal}{m}{n}

\Umathchardef\stixc@lA "0 \symstixtwocal "1D49C
\Umathchardef\stixc@lB "0 \symstixtwocal "0212C
\Umathchardef\stixc@lC "0 \symstixtwocal "1D49E
\Umathchardef\stixc@lD "0 \symstixtwocal "1D49F
\Umathchardef\stixc@lE "0 \symstixtwocal "02130
\Umathchardef\stixc@lF "0 \symstixtwocal "02131
\Umathchardef\stixc@lG "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4A2
\Umathchardef\stixc@lH "0 \symstixtwocal "0210B
\Umathchardef\stixc@lI "0 \symstixtwocal "02110
\Umathchardef\stixc@lJ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4A5
\Umathchardef\stixc@lK "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4A6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lL "0 \symstixtwocal "02112
\Umathchardef\stixc@lM "0 \symstixtwocal "02133
\Umathchardef\stixc@lN "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4A9
\Umathchardef\stixc@lO "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4AA
\Umathchardef\stixc@lP "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4AB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lQ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4AC
\Umathchardef\stixc@lR "0 \symstixtwocal "0211B
\Umathchardef\stixc@lS "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4AE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lT "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4AF
\Umathchardef\stixc@lU "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B0
\Umathchardef\stixc@lV "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B1
\Umathchardef\stixc@lW "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B2
\Umathchardef\stixc@lX "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B3
\Umathchardef\stixc@lY "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B4
\Umathchardef\stixc@lZ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B5

\Umathchardef\stixc@la "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lb "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B7
\Umathchardef\stixc@lc "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B8
\Umathchardef\stixc@ld "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4B9
\Umathchardef\stixc@le "0 \symstixtwocal "0212F
\Umathchardef\stixc@lf "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4BB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lg "0 \symstixtwocal "0210A
\Umathchardef\stixc@lh "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4BD
\Umathchardef\stixc@li "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4BE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lj "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4BF
\Umathchardef\stixc@lk "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C0
\Umathchardef\stixc@ll "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C1
\Umathchardef\stixc@lm "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C2
\Umathchardef\stixc@ln "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C3
\Umathchardef\stixc@lo "0 \symstixtwocal "02134
\Umathchardef\stixc@lp "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C5
\Umathchardef\stixc@lq "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lr "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C7
\Umathchardef\stixc@ls "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C8
\Umathchardef\stixc@lt "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4C9
\Umathchardef\stixc@lu "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CA
\Umathchardef\stixc@lv "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lw "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CC
\Umathchardef\stixc@lx "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CD
\Umathchardef\stixc@ly "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lz "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4CF

\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfA "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D0
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfB "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D1
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfC "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D2
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfD "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D3
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfE "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D4
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfF "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D5
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfG "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfH "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D7
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfI "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D8
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfJ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4D9
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfK "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DA
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfL "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfM "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DC
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfN "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DD
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfO "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfP "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4DF
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfQ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E0
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfR "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E1
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfS "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E2
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfT "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E3
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfU "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E4
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfV "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E5
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfW "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfX "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E7
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfY "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E8
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfZ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4E9

\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfa "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4EA
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfb "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4EB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfc "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4EC
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfd "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4ED
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfe "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4EE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbff "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4EF
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfg "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F0
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfh "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F1
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfi "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F2
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfj "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F3
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfk "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F4
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfl "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F5
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfm "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F6
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfn "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F7
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfo "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F8
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfp "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4F9
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfq "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FA
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfr "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FB
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfs "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FC
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbft "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FD
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfu "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FE
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfv "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4FF
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfw "0 \symstixtwocal "1D500
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfx "0 \symstixtwocal "1D501
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfy "0 \symstixtwocal "1D502
\Umathchardef\stixc@lbfz "0 \symstixtwocal "1D503

\def\ifiscseq#1{\ifcat$\expandafter\@gobble\string#1$\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}

\def\stix@@cal#1#2\@nil{%
    \ifiscseq{#1}{\ifcsdef{stixc@l\@xp\@gobble\string#1}{\csname stixc@l\@xp\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}{#1}}{%not a cs
    \csname stixc@l#1\endcsname}    
    \ifblank{#2}{\relax}{\stix@@cal #2\@nil}}

\def\stix@@calbf#1#2\@nil{%
    \ifiscseq{#1}{\ifcsdef{stixc@lbf\@xp\@gobble\string#1}{\csname stixc@lbf\@xp\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}{#1}}{%not a cs
    \csname stixc@lbf#1\endcsname}  
    \ifblank{#2}{\relax}{\stix@@calbf #2\@nil}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\stixcal}[1]{\stix@@cal#1\@nil}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\stixcalbf}[1]{\stix@@calbf#1\@nil}
```

This works beautifully. I know there is probably a way to make it cleaner, and I welcome input in that regard.
Now, if I add

```
\newfontface\StixTwoMathOne{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[NFSSFamily=stixtwochan,Script=Math,StylisticSet=1]
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochan}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
```

and

```
\def\stix@@chan#1#2\@nil{%
    \ifiscseq{#1}{\ifcsdef{stixch@n\@xp\@gobble\string#1}{\csname stixch@n\@xp\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}{#1}}{%not a cs
    \csname stixch@n#1\endcsname}   
    \ifblank{#2}{\relax}{\stix@@chan #2\@nil}}

\def\stix@@chanbf#1#2\@nil{%
    \ifiscseq{#1}{\ifcsdef{stixch@nbf\@xp\@gobble\string#1}{\csname stixch@nbf\@xp\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}{#1}}{%not a cs
    \csname stixch@nbf#1\endcsname} 
    \ifblank{#2}{\relax}{\stix@@chanbf #2\@nil}}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\stixchan}[1]{\stix@@chan#1\@nil}
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\stixchanbf}[1]{\stix@@chanbf#1\@nil}
```

at the bottom and the entire gamut of lines of the form

```
\Umathchardef\stixch@nA "0 \symstixtwochan "1D49C
```

in between, I get a plethora of errors beginning with

```
\symstixtwocal=\mathgroup15

! LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 ...bolFont{stixtwochan}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
                                                  
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.117 \Umathchardef\stixch@nA "0 \symstixtwochan
                                                 "1D49C
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Bad math family (119964).
l.117 ...ardef\stixch@nA "0 \symstixtwochan "1D49C
                                                  
Since I expected to read a number between 0 and 255,
I changed this one to zero.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \Umathchardef 
l.118 \Umathchardef
                   \stixch@nB "0 \symstixtwochan "0212C
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

I've included what I think is relevant.  The errors that follow are repetitive and I think they all (including the last three shown) stem from the very first error because the 17th mathgroup is never declared.

This entire effort has been aimed at getting around this limitation.  Again, I am using XeTeX to compile with `fontspec`, not `unicode-math`, because I do not wish to replace MathTime Pro II as my math font. All my text fonts are OpenType.  I am trying to move as many non-`mtpro2` math fonts to OpenType as possible.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could make it easier for people to help and provide a test file: none of the `\Umathchardef\stixc@lJ "0 \symstixtwocal "1D4A5` which you did post are relevant to this error. Just a single self contained code block would be enough

Comment: @David Carlisle Noted (still learning the protocol :-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler test file would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
%\patchcmd\DeclareSymbolFont@m@dropped{15}{255}{\typeout{patched}}{\ERROR}
\makeatother
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\StixTwoMathOne
[NFSSFamily=stixtwochan,Script=Math,StylisticSet=1]
{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochan}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochana}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanb}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanc}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochand}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochane}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanf}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochang}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanh}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochani}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanj}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochank}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanl}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanm}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochann}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$x$
\end{document}
```

Uncommenting line 5 gives latex a hint there are more than 16 families available

Comment: I presume that the `\patchcmd` needs to appear before `\usepackage{fontspec}`.  I should have mentioned that I am using LyX, which puts constraints on the order packages are loaded.  I may be able to figure out a way to get it inserted properly, but is it necessary?  I inserted lines 4-6 at the top of my package (`etoolbox` is already loaded) and I am getting a new set of errors.  Before I go into detail, I thought I would ask about where in the order `\patchcmd` needs to be executed.

Comment: no, anywhere before `\DeclareSymbolFont{stixtwochanl}{TU}{stixtwochan}{m}{n}` near the end which is where it hit 15 and gave the error @MikePugh

Comment: Once you go past 15 you can not use latex `\DeclareMathSymbol` (which is why the limit was kept but you can use  `\Umathchardef` as you showed ( `\DeclareMathSymbol`  uses `\mathchardef`) @MikePugh

Comment: So what would happen if other packages using `DeclareSymbolFont` were loaded prior to this one?  I am getting errors (which I can't post in the comment in detail) that are mostly `! Missing number, treated as zero.` and `Missing character: There is no ^^O in font TeX Gyre Termes/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;mapping=tex-text;!` (Missing glyphs!) that I was not getting before and they appear to be generated by the `Umathchardef` statements that were okay previously.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it.  It was not enough to put the `\patchcmd` at the start of the package.  Moving it to the beginning of the non-LyX-generated section of the preamble solved the problem.  Thank you again for all of your help!