# Power and Subscript "Push" Each Other

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I'm facing an issue where the superscript and subscript do not align:

[image]

Now I'm using a command I defined to create this:

```
\newcommand{\pow}[2]{\ensuremath{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}^{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{#2}}}}}}}

\newcommand{\sub}[2]{\ensuremath{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}_{\reflectbox{\ensuremath{#2}}}}}}}
```

It's quite messy, but all it does is `#1^#2` and then reflecting the whole thing, and then reflecting the individual symbols again.

Here's how I call the commands:

```
\[\sub{\pow{\iKaaf}{س}}{س}\]
```

`iKaaf` being the long shape--the base. Order matters. If I use `pow` before `sub`, the superscript and subscript would be pushed, just in reverse order. How could I fix this problem? Also, as a side-question, how could I make automatically scale the powers and subscripts? Using

```
\newcommand{\pow}[2]{\ensuremath{{{}^#2}#1}}
\newcommand{\sub}[2]{\ensuremath{{{}_#2}#1}}
```

works, but I cannot "nest" them into each other, since it creates problems such as these:
[image]

when `\[\pow{\lSeen}{\pow{\two}{\two}}\]` is used.

**EDIT**: MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\input{commands} % where I get the pow and sub commands

\begin{document}

\[\sub{\pow{\iKaaf}{س}}{س}\]

\end{document}
```

I used [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/cant-get-unicode-symbols-in-math-mode) in order to directly input Arabic in math mode.

Comment: Do you want right to left math in general or only for the `sub` and `pow` macros?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Really RTL math in general. I just don't understand why that specific macro isn't working well.

Comment: To understand why the specific macro doesn't work think about it in boxes: `\reflectbox` takes a box, reflects it and then outputs the reflected box. In your case you are reflecting it again, but that doesn't change that you wrapped your content in a box TeX can't really look into. So TeX more or less sees the `\pow{\iKaaf}{س}` as a rectangle corresponding to it's bounding box and places the subscript next to this box.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the built-in `\mathdirection` to change the math direction?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes. My ignorance of such macro is the reason :)

Comment: Basically you need to use LuaLaTeX and then you can set `\mathdir TRT`. After that, your math should be in right-to-left. (It might confuse some packages though) (Disclaimer: I can neither read nor write any right to left language, so I don't have any experience with it. I would be interested to hear if it works for you though)

Comment: @MarcelKrüger It works fine. It gives an error if I tried to use the XITS Math font when I try to import it using the unicode-math package, giving me errors like, "This is already defined by the amsmath or amssymb package." Eventually, I had to switch to using the Amiri font. Amiri doesn't have any RTL support for math, unlike the XITS math font, so I had to leave the amssymb  and the Amiri font for the XITS math font. It works now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123765/discussion-between-bored-comedy-and-marcel-kruger).