# Make the $, equation and align math environments globally blue

Tags: color, environments

I'd like to make all my math blue. So far I only use the $, equation and align environment, so it'd we nice it it worked for those. If it works for others, that'd be even greater.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{blue}}
\everydisplay{\color{blue}}

\begin{document}
    Let $\vec{v}$ be some vector. A fancy one.

    \begin{align}
        \vec{v} = \vec{a} \\
                &= + \vec{b}
    \end{align}

    \begin{equation}
        \vec{v} = \vec{a} + \vec{b}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I get

```
untitled.tex|14 error| Improper \halign inside $$'s
```

I know I could just write my own environments but I really would love to just tell it: Make everything blue no matter what.

Comment: Please tell us whether you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document.

Comment: @Mico: I don't think that this is relevant in this case as all three end up with the same error message (tested for you)

Comment: You can colour the math font(s) (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201239/cant-get-unicode-symbols-in-math-mode), but requires `font-spec` or `unicode-math`, so not a pdflatex solution. You only want specified environments to apply blue text/maths, elsewhere is unchanged, is that correct? Some solution sets will be engine-specific.

Comment: @MarkusG. - Sorry about the purpose of my earlier comment not being clear. The point is not that some TeX executables might avoid the error condition generated by `\everymath`. Rather, it's that XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX -- more precisely, the `fontspec` package which runs only under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX -- offer a solution that isn't available under pdfLaTeX. To wit, if the `unicode-math` package (which loads `fontspec` automatically) is loaded, then the option `Color=0000FF` while executing `\setmathfont` will render all inline math and display math material in blue; no need for `\everydisplay`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\everymath{\color{blue}}


\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\color{blue}}
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th\normalfont\color{blue}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Let $\vec{v}$ be some vector. A fancy one.

    \begin{align}
        \vec{v} = \vec{a} \\
                &= + \vec{b}
    \end{align}

    \begin{equation}
        \vec{v} = \vec{a} + \vec{b}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but what about `\[...\]`?

Comment: @campa it wasn't in the question:-)  `\g@addto@macro\[{\color{blue}}`

Comment: But the inline math isn't blue ... (unless I'm going blind).

Comment: @barbarabeeton The `$\vec{v}$` is blue in the output.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- -- Logically, it should be.  I guess I'll have to have my browser checked.  (It *has* been known to misbehave.)

Answer (score 11):

If you use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to compile your document, you may render *all* inline math and display math material in blue automatically by employing the `unicode-math` package and setting the option `Color=0000FF` while executing `\setmathfont`. E.g.,

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[Color=0000FF]{Latin Modern Math} % set a suitable math font
```

Here's an MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Color=0000FF]
\begin{document}
Let $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$, and $\vec{v}$ denote vectors. Suppose
\begin{equation}\label{eq:new}
     \vec{v} = \vec{a} + \vec{b}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: More than once when I had a font-related problem I used LuaLatex. I never experienced any compatibility problem or whatever. So why doesn't everyone simply use LuaLatex? (I am myself guilty of using pdflatex by default as well.)

Comment: @JohannesLinkels - You raise a very good question. :-) My impression is that a large part of all LaTeX users are taught the bare minimum (and often less than that!) of LaTeX by their college or grad school advisers, who in turn learned LaTeX from their advisers, etc. An econometrician/mathematician friend of mine, while we were chatting about the generally abysmally low levels of LaTeX proficiency of what appears to be a clear majority of mathematicians, once opined, "most mathematicians are neanderthals." That may have been a needless insult to neanderthals...

Comment: @JohannesLinkels - In truth, until about 5 or 6 years ago, using Lua(La)TeX for production work was something best left to the more adventurous spirits. Fortunately, LuaTeX has stabilized since then, and nowadays 99.99% of all alleged bugs in LuaLaTeX are not bugs but user coding errors.