# How to type all math alphanumeric symbols in Unicode in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode, unicode-math, amssymb

Take a look at the picture below:
[image]

This is the `Unicode` I want to use!
PDF address: https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf

Comment: do you mean you want that as output or are you asking how to type unicode as input ? either way use the unicode-math package

Comment: pdflatex doesn't support Unicode. If you want to use these symbols and know how to type them, simply use them, find out a font which has all those symbols and with that font compile the document with any of the Unicode-compliant engines, i.e., xelatex/lualatex. (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25251)

Comment: You might want to declare the entire Unicode-block with the `expl3` loop found at the end of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201248

Comment:  = ² is math mode

Comment: @gopoke  = ^{2} would work with unicode -math and make the same output as E=mc^{2}  Unicode superscripts (which you do not mention in your question) are best avoided in math typesetting

Answer (score 1):

Using `unicode-math` (and luatex or xetex) you can use Unicode input or more classical ascii command forms, for the same output.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

$ = ²$, $$

$E=mc^2$, $\symbf{\theta}$

\end{document}
```

Comment:  = ², !